# onItemCheckedStateChanged() is called only once on custom ExpandableListView

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I am trying to implement multiple selection in my custom `ExpandableListView` here is the Java code and group layout:

**Java**

```
mExpandable.setChoiceMode(ExpandableListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
        mExpandable.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode actionMode, int position, long id, boolean checked) {
                if(DEBUG) Log.i("mFragmentList","onItemCheckedStateChanged()");

                if(mExpandable.getCheckedItemCount() == 0)
                    actionMode.setSubtitle("Check some items!");
                else if(mExpandable.getCheckedItemCount() == 1)
                    actionMode.setSubtitle("1 item selected");
                else
                    actionMode.setSubtitle(mExpandable.getCheckedItemCount() + " items selected");
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, android.view.Menu menu) {
                actionMode.setTitle("Select Items");
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, android.view.Menu menu) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode actionMode, MenuItem menuItem) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode actionMode) {

            }
        });
```

**group_row.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    style="@style/activated">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:src="@drawable/ball" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvGroupName"
        android:paddingLeft="35dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#FFFF0000"
        android:textSize="17sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

When I long click on a item the item get selected and `ActionMode` is created but if I want to select another item the item gets expanded and `onItemCheckedStateChanged()` is not called anymore so I can't select more than one item. I tried to put `CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL` in XML but I couldn't select even one item. What am I missing? Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Andres, First of all, thanks a lot for the source code.  I've tried to import the source code with MultiChoiceMode that you posted at this link:  https://github.com/dragondgold/AnimatedExpandableListView  in the Eclipse, but it won't work.  I know you did it in the Android Studio.  How can I make it work in Eclipse?  Thank you

Comment: You should create a project from source code I think or you can just create a project and copy the. java files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I finally solved it with a workaround.

```
mExpandable.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView expandableListView, View view, int i, long l) {
                if(actionModeEnabled)
                    expandableListView.setItemChecked(i, !expandableListView.isItemChecked(i));

                return actionModeEnabled;
            }
        });

mExpandable.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode actionMode, int position, long id, boolean checked) {
        if(mExpandable.getCheckedItemCount() == 1)
            actionMode.setSubtitle("1 item selected");
        else
            actionMode.setSubtitle(mExpandable.getCheckedItemCount() + " items selected");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, android.view.Menu menu) {
        actionModeEnabled = true;
        actionMode.setTitle("Select Items");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, android.view.Menu menu) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode actionMode, MenuItem menuItem) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode actionMode) {
        actionModeEnabled = false;
    }
});
```

So when I long-press some item the Action Mode is enabled and the first item is checked as expected. To continue selecting items I set an `OnGroupClickListener`, so now when I click on an item I select/deselect it using `setItemChecked()` and return `true` when the Action Mode is enable so the list doesn't get expanded, just selected.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer works almost correctly for me, but I have an issue.

The problem is on here:

```
@Override
public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode actionMode, int position, long id, boolean checked) {
    if(mExpandable.getCheckedItemCount() == 1)
        actionMode.setSubtitle("1 item selected");
    else
        actionMode.setSubtitle(mExpandable.getCheckedItemCount() + " items selected");
}
```

When the groups are collapse it works fine. But for example, if I have this structure:

```
- Group 1
    + Child 1
- Group 2
    + Child 2
```

If I press long click in the Group 2, the position in onItemCheckedStateChanged that I expect is 1 (cause we start on 0, Group 1 = position 0 and Group 2 = position 1). But the method has position = 2! So it selects a row that doesn't exist. And I think this behavior it is because when the children are expanded, Group 2 has index 2 (in the example case). How to fix this for using CAB with the group rows correctly? As if it was a normal ListView.

Comment: Yes I had this problem too I don't know how to fix it so I decided to use https://github.com/tjerkw/Android-SlideExpandableListView which also animate the expand/collapse action. MultiChoiceMode was not working so I ported it to Android Studio and modified it to work with MultiChoiceMode, see the code here: https://github.com/dragondgold/AnimatedExpandableListView

Comment: I tried and it works fine! I just I am having an issue. After the adapter launches listView.smoothScrollBy(..), which it makes the listview scrolls when is necessary, when I click an element, the first click is ignored (and you have to click twice). I am trying to do something with onInterceptTouchEventbut it always fails in some cases. Is that happen to you too?

Comment: I'm not sure I am understanding you. You say when `listView.smoothScrollBy(..)` is used in the library to scroll the list to make the clicked item visible the next click event is ignored? I am not having this issue.

Comment: @DIFTOR email me with a screenshot or video showing what's happening maybe I can help you.